Why did an Arthur Ransome Club first start in Japan in particular?
The Arthur Ransome Club, "the first organization dedicated to promoting and celebrating the works of Arthur Ransome", was established in Japan in 1987, predating The Arthur Ransome Society in Britain by some years. Given that Arthur Ransome was a British author, writing books in English that were very clearly set in England with very British characters, how come the first appreciative society dedicated to him and his work was established in Japan? The Wikipedia page linked above is very sparse on detail; what led to his work becoming so popular and celebrated in Japan, more (apparently) than anywhere else in the world?
